# Which type in C# can render this json collection

Tags: c#, json, types

which `type` in C# can render this json result ?

```
[[30.51,46.30],[31.54,45.83]]
```

I tried `IDictionary<decimal, decimal>` but `dictionary` is not supported for serialization and I can't use third-party component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type you are looking for is `List<List<double>>`. Using [System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
string json = "[[30.51,46.30],[31.54,45.83]]";
var listOfLists = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<List<double>>>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

a `list of lists`
or an `array of arrays`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

An excellent C#/.NET solution for converting to and from JSON. Serializable too.

Comment: Why can't you use a third-party component?

Comment: Do you have any Idea for handle that with .NET library ?

Comment: Check out some of the examples. Pretty straightforward.